# Marathon ITE , Java swing Applet , is it a must to have a local copy of the applet?

Tags: applet, automation, gui-testing, marathon, marathontesting

I'm new to marathon , just started with a simple swing based applet automation . In the configuration,we specify the local path of the html page containing the applet .

Is it possible to automate in marathon without specifying the local path of the HTML page  ??? 
Why because , say my application is hosted on some server , in which case access to the source code of the application and applet will not be there .
Is there any alternate ????

Answer (score 0):

MarathonITE internally uses appletviewer to launch the application. It is not needed to use local copy. In that case, use command line launcher and provide a script file that launches appletviewer with appropriate arguments.